# lstm neural network abnormally output the same value

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm currently studying and trying to improve a python script, which purpose is to predict stock market moves (a very simple one).

The Problem : I'm getting the same output value and I don't really understand why, since it's suppose to be more like this chart (red line is the prediction I should get and the blue line is the true data) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvQvY.png

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
import math, time
import itertools
from sklearn import preprocessing
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM

def get_stock_data(stock_name, normalized=0):
    url = 'http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=11&b=15&c=2011&d=29&e=10&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv' % stock_name

    col_names = ['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close']
    stocks = pd.read_csv(url, header=0, names=col_names) 
    df = pd.DataFrame(stocks)
    date_split = df['Date'].str.split('-').str
    df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'] = date_split
    df["Volume"] = df["Volume"] / 10000
    df.drop(df.columns[[0,3,5,6, 7,8,9]], axis=1, inplace=True) 
    return df

stock_name = 'GOOGL'
df = get_stock_data(stock_name,0)
df.head()

today = datetime.date.today()
file_name = stock_name+'_stock_%s.csv' % today
df.to_csv(file_name)

df['High'] = df['High'] / 100
df['Open'] = df['Open'] / 100
df['Close'] = df['Close'] / 100
df.head(5)

def load_data(stock, seq_len):
    amount_of_features = len(stock.columns)
    data = stock.as_matrix() #pd.DataFrame(stock)
    sequence_length = seq_len + 1
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    result = np.array(result)
    row = round(0.9 * result.shape[0])
    train = result[:int(row), :]
    x_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1][:,-1]
    x_test = result[int(row):, :-1]
    y_test = result[int(row):, -1][:,-1]

    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], amount_of_features))
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], amount_of_features))  

    return [x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test]

def build_model2(layers):
        d = 0.2
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(layers[1], layers[0]), return_sequences=True))
        model.add(Dropout(d))
        model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(layers[1], layers[0]), return_sequences=False))
        model.add(Dropout(d))
        model.add(Dense(16,init='uniform',activation='relu'))        
        model.add(Dense(1,init='uniform',activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

window = 22
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_data(df[::-1], window)
print("X_train", X_train.shape)
print("y_train", y_train.shape)
print("X_test", X_test.shape)
print("y_test", y_test.shape)

model = build_model2([3,window,1])

model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=512,
    nb_epoch=500,
    validation_split=0.1,
    verbose=1)

trainScore = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print('Train Score: %.2f MSE (%.2f RMSE)' % (trainScore[0], math.sqrt(trainScore[0])))

testScore = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test Score: %.2f MSE (%.2f RMSE)' % (testScore[0],math.sqrt(testScore[0])))

# print(X_test[-1])
diff=[]
ratio=[]
p = model.predict(X_test)
for u in range(len(y_test)):
    pr = p[u][0]
    ratio.append((y_test[u]/pr)-1)
    diff.append(abs(y_test[u]- pr))
    #print(u, y_test[u], pr, (y_test[u]/pr)-1, abs(y_test[u]- pr))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2

plt2.plot(p,color='red', label='prediction')
plt2.plot(y_test,color='blue', label='y_test')
plt2.legend(loc='upper left')
plt2.show()
```

The output I'm getting : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TVRb.png

(I've already tried to change batch size and number of epochs)

I'm currently using (on macosx sierra) :

Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan  2 2017, 18:14:29)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.

Every module used in the previous code is up to date (April 24, 2017)

I may have forgotten some infos, don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks

Comment: What leads you to believe it should output the original image you linked?

Comment: Because it did it once and at least I expect the script to output something different from a simple straight line (something that follows the average for example, or something like that). What makes me think there is a problem is that, now, no matter what set of data I input (apple stock, google,...), the output is always a straight red line. I'm new to neural network so to be honest I don't really know what should be the expected output. And if it's a normal behavior how can I find what triggers the correct behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to scale your data to mean=0?

Answer (score 0):

Change `nb_epoch=500` to `nb_epoch=2`
and you will see that the LSTM will work fine.